# what can be reason of admob ad not showing?

Tags: flutter, admob

In my flutter app admob ad works with test id on simulator.However it does not show on real phone.Since 30 october application is on google play store.Although on admob console it is ready for showing add, the application that has been downloaded from play store does not show add.
On ios all ads show perfectly.
I share screenshoots of admob account for better understanding.
[image]

[image]

I have searched this problem on stacoverflow but not find any solution in detail.